# How to get jquery object from $(.class)[0]

Tags: javascript, jquery

So the question is simple
How to reduce this code and get jquery object  of needed element? Or is it the best way?

```
  $($('.myclass')[0])
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. `$('.myclass')` will return a jQuery object, `$('.myclass')[0]` will return the DOMElements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you want to get jquery object of first element then  use `:first` or `:eq(0)` selectors:

```
$('.myclass:first');
```

or

```
$('.myclass:eq(0)');
```

Answer (score 2):

I have this solution

yes, using selector like .myclass:first is the simple way but according jsperf.com

```
$('.myclass').first();
```

have more performance, fast and recommended

Comment: Just as an addition. The performance is better as `.myclass:first` or `.myclass:eq(0)` are selectors that are not supported natively by the current browsers. As of that jQuery needs to fallback to its internal Selector engine ([Sizzle](http://sizzlejs.com/)), which is slower then the native one. Another note: please don't blindly rely on jspref results, a horrible count of _performance_ tests are completely wrong, as those tests are design the wrong way, often measuring something else then the actual problem.